# Agora Signal Login fails on https

Tags: https, agora.io

I'm using [Agora Signaling API for Web](https://docs.agora.io/en/Signaling/signal_web?platform=Web). Using the sample code when I login over an http connection it logs-in normally, works pretty fine on my local machines as well.

```js
this.signal = Signal('APIKEY');
this.session = this.signal.login('account_id');
```

But when I switch to https (SSL Certificate) connection, the login method throws an error [image]

If someone had experienced such an issue, it would be great to share how it was resolved? Didn't find much help on internet regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was the issue with the signal.js file, I followed the tutorial from 
[Agora Signaling Tutorial](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Signaling/tree/master/Agora-Signaling-Tutorial-Web) and used the AgoraSig.js file instead and everything started working fine.

Thanks.